# Does Mathematica v.8 (or will v.9) run on Windows 8 systems with ARM processors? (like the MS Surface Tablet)

Tags: version-8, windows, compatibility

Today I was reading that the Microsoft *Surface RT* is available for pre-order. (For the curious, click [here](http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2012/10/as-surface-goes-on-sale-today-microsoft-seeks-to-reinvent-tablet/).)

I know the version of Widows 8 that runs on x86 processors should be compatible already with Mathematica 8... but what about the version of Windows 8---called Windows 8 RT---designed for ARM processor devices, like Microsoft's Surface device?

Also, from what I've read there will also be an Intel version, called the *Surface Pro*, that will run Windows 8 Pro. (Note I'm not sure if this will be an ARM or x86 Intel processor.)

Summarizing my question(s): Will Mathematica run on the *Surface RT* or the *Surface Pro*?

Info about the Surface on Wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Surface).

Comment: Mathematica 8 does not list Windows 8 on their supported operating systems:

Mathematica 9 hasn't been released and there are no details about it available.

Comment: I don't think hypothetical questions about products that are not yet released should be asked.

Comment: Mathematica 9 came out and it doesn't support ARM so I guess you can accept my answer now ;)

Comment: @burger.ga - cha-ching! (And FWIW, I've crashed v9 3 times already in the first couple of hours with it---all just clicking around in the documentation center.)

Comment: There is an free(!) ARM version available for the Raspberry Pi, see http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mathematica 8 will only run on the Surface Pro since it has a x86 processor (Ivy Bridge Core i5) and runs Windows 8 Pro (which is the same as the desktop/laptop version). The Surface RT will have an ARM processor which means that if you want software to run on it, you should recompile it for ARM. Mathematica 8 is not compiled for ARM, so it will not run.

Most likely Mathematica 9 won't be compiled for ARM either.
I say this because Mathematica needs quite a bit of computation power, usually not available on ARM machines, so I think it is not a very interesting market for Wolfram.

So I would go for the Surface Pro, since Mathematica 8 (and 9) will definitely run on that.

EDIT (24-12-2014): Apparently it does run on ARM since there is a free(!) version available for the Raspberry Pi (http://www.wolfram.com/raspberry-pi), no word on Microsoft Surface version.

Comment: On the other hand, Wolfram has been talking of a player for iPad, and they have already presented a beta on one of their events. Since the player has all the calculation capacity of the pro version, apparently they have developed all that was missing. So, you never know...

Comment: From what I understand the Player app is only for presentations/demonstrations. To make the notebooks for  Player you'll still need the normal version of Mathematica. Moreover, an i5 has a lot more computation than an ARM device, or an Ipad/Iphone for that matter.

Comment: I wonder how much is there in the full version kernel that's missing from the player.  What can go in a CDF Manipulate is not really that restricted.